# Kinematics in two dimensions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, centripetal-force

Is it right (theoretically) if we assume rectilinear motion as a circular motion in a circle of infinite radius? If yes, is it right to say that the centripetal force =0?

Comment: You can assume an infinite radius circle and it will tend to a linear motion. If the radius gets close to infinite, then the centripetal acceleration tends to zero, yes. But, what are you after with this? do you think this implies something else? Moreover, the title is not describing correctly the mean text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is an acceptable perspective, and yes, the centripetal *acceleration* is zero.

Side note: Keep in mind that there is not a specific force which is centripetal force. Many different types of force can act perpendicular to the velocity and produce centripetal acceleration: gravity, Lorentz E&M, friction, tension, elastic.